# How to recommend most similar users using Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I have a data about user preferences for specific items in the form:

```
user, item, preference  
1,    75,   0.89  
2,    168,  0.478  
2,    99,   0.321  
3,    31,   0.012
```

For each user, I need to make a top N most similar users based on their preferences.The system has thousands of users, and items. Recommendations would be generated in batch process, and served on Elasticsearch.
In Mahout, simple algorithm that would do it might look like:

```
  val similarity:UserSimilarity=new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel)
  val neighborhood:UserNeighborhood  = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.75, similarity, dataModel)
  val userBasedRecommender:UserBasedRecommender  = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(dataModel, neighborhood, similarity);
  val userid=1
  val howMany=10
  val mostSimilarUserIDs = userBasedRecommender.mostSimilarUserIDs(userid, howMany);
```

I would like to implement that using Spark ML, but could not find any similar example that could help me to move on.

So far, I implemented approach using cosine similarity that compare one user features vector with other users:

```
def cosineSimilarity(vec1: DoubleMatrix, vec2: DoubleMatrix): Double=
{
    vec1.dot(vec2)/(vec1.norm2()*vec2.norm2())
}
def user2usersimilarity(userid:Integer, recNumber:Integer): Unit ={
    val userFactor=model.userFeatures.lookup(userid).head
    val userVector=new DoubleMatrix(userFactor)
    val s1=cosineSimilarity(userVector,userVector)
    val sims=model.userFeatures.map{case(id,factor)=>
        val factorVector=new DoubleMatrix(factor)
        val sim=cosineSimilarity(factorVector, userVector)
        (id,sim)
    }
    val sortedSims=sims.top(recNumber+1)(Ordering.by[(Int, Double),Double] {case(id, similarity)=>similarity})
    println(sortedSims.slice(1,recNumber+1).mkString("\n"))
 }
```

This approach works fine with the MovieLens dataset in terms of quality of recommendations. However, my concern is related to performance of such algorithm. Since I have to generate recommendations for all users in the system, with this approach I would compare each user with all other users in the system.

I would appreciate if somebody could suggest how to limit comparison of the user to top N neighbors, or some other algorithm that would work better in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a clustering algorithm ?, train once, deploy model , use model to identify in which cluster a new example belongs to, and then randomly recommend users in the same cluster ? Its just an idea...

Comment: Actually, that is something similar to what I did implement few days ago. Though my solution uses two models. First one, uses Spark ML K-means to identify clusters of students based on the courses they are assigned to. In the next iteration, ALS model is used to recommend users from the same cluster that belong to the same cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spark *Collaborative Filtering* using *Alternating Least Squares*: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html

it is built precisely for this case.

> **Collaborative filtering**
>
> Collaborative filtering is commonly used for recommender systems.
>   These techniques aim to fill in the missing entries of a user-item
>   association matrix. spark.ml currently supports model-based
>   collaborative filtering, in which users and products are described by
>   a small set of latent factors that can be used to predict missing
>   entries. spark.ml uses the alternating least squares (ALS) algorithm
>   to learn these latent factors.

Given that you have actual preferences/ratings you can use the ***explicit preferences*** approach  (as opposed to *implicit*).